# Xcode connect view controllers

Tags: xcode

I am new to Xcode, my XCode is Version 11.3.1 (11C504). I tried to connect the default view controller to my newly added view controller on the main.storyboard, on the lab computer(lower version, 9.0 I believe) it's connecting normally, but when I connect with my laptop, it shows gap on the top, and when running the simulator, it is showing screens after screens when I click buttons. Can anyone tell me where to correct this?

[image]

When connected to the view controller, it shows a gap there
[image: simulator view, shows a different layer of screens]

Comment: Can anyone comment on this question if I have posted to a proper place?

Comment: Fixed with navigation controller on XCode 11.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with navigation controller on XCode 11.3.1